# Redimiento malo en Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, windows, ubuntu

Actualmente tenemos dos equipos que hacen de servidor de bdd para una agenda electrónica:

Core 2 Duo
2 GB RAM
1 TB HDD
Windows server 2008

este equipo lleva dos años trabajando y se va a cambiar porque ha comenzado a fallar de vez en cuando.

El equipo que lo reemplaza es un HP Proliant con un

Xeon de 6 núcleos
32 GB de RAM
4 TB HDD en Raid 0
Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

el problema que tenemos es que al migrar la bdd de Windows a ubuntu, las consultas a la bdd se ejecutan demasiado lento y se rompen algunas funcionalidades del sistema al generar reportes en pdf.

por ejemplo, al llamar una vista en la máquina con windows, el tiempo de ejecución del query es de < 1 seg. mientras que en la máquina con ubuntu el tiempo de ejecucíon oscila alrededor de ~ 41 segundos (ejecutados desde workbench).

Ambas instancias de Mysql tienen la configuración por defecto al instalarse, y la versión es 5.6 en ambas.

No tengo idea por donde revisar ya que no tengo mucha experiencia utilizando linux.

Comment: Compara los planes de ejecución de las consultas.

Comment: debes ejecutar la consulta desde el servidor, asi garantizas que esta lento las consulta, puede que sea el acceso a la red, un firewall o el propio router

Comment: ejecutando la consulta desde el servidor, directamente en la terminal de mysql continua tardando al rededor de 40 segundos.

Comment: ¿has revisado de que no hayan otros procesos ejecutándose que estén consumiendo recursos? ¿que te indican los logs cuando realizas una consulta? podrías probar a activar el [slow query log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22609627/895789) y ver que te muestra